# Application crashed while moving to next activity

Tags: android

I can't understand what's the issue the app worked fine but now it's crashing again and again please spare some time to help me out

**logcat**

```
   2020-04-23 03:16:58.315 23244-23244/com.studenthelper.bscithelp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL   EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.studenthelper.bscithelp, PID: 23244
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.studenthelper.bscithelp/com.studenthelper.bscithelp.login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2914)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.studenthelper.bscithelp.login.onCreate(login.java:41)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7131)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app     theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
    at   com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:248)
2020-04-23 03:16:58.316 23244-23244/com.studenthelper.bscithelp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:222)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:150)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:120)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:424)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:396)
        ... 30 more
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".login"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/loginimg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/signin"
    android:transitionName="logo_image"

    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/logintxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/purpose"
    android:text="@string/wlcm"
    android:transitionName="logo_text"

    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sgn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/chil"
    android:text="@string/signin"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sgn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:hint="USERNAME"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/primaryDarkColor"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/usrPass"
        android:hint="PASSWORD"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/primaryDarkColor"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/frgt_pass"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:text="FORGET PASSWORD"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:elevation="0dp"

        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SIGN IN"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryDarkColor"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:fontFamily="@font/android_7"

        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NEW USER ? JOIN NOW"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:elevation="0dp"

        />




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The components you're using are not compatible with the theme you have set for your application. try changing the theme in your res/values/styles.xml file and change the theme to Theme.MaterialComponents

Comment: i didnt get i hvae used <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> and it worked before

Comment: if i use your recommended method it totally changes the look of ui but app doesnt crash i was using noaction bar and it worked perfect before

Comment: Maybe you've updated the dependencies for the Material design package and the version used is causing the issue? check the version for "com.google.android.material:material" in your app's gradle file

Comment: yes i updated to latest one

Comment: thanks for help now i could sleep thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it worked!! I posted an answer to the question so anyone else with the same issue can find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you've updated your dependencies for `Material Design`, you could try reverting back to a previous version in your app's gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:x.y.z'
```

Once you've reverted, just run a gradle sync and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the logcat there is:

> The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).

So you have to use MaterialComponents instead of AppCompat

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use **`TextInputLayout`**. If you take a look at the package name which this element is bundled with, it is **`com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`**. It says **`Material`**, which in Android means the new Material Design Library. If you want to use any element from this library, you have to make your android applications's base style implement this.

#### SOLUTION

Go to **`app->res->values->styles.xml`**.

You will need to change the Base application theme's parent to the following:

```
<resources>
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: thank you for response but using it changes my ui it worked fine using Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar but now its not

Comment: Yes Material Theme changes certain aspect of your theme for the overall app. You have no choice but to fix them.